How to find running notebooks
Currently as a DBA of a large database, routinely we get ridiculous or bad queries.
When they come from Apache Zeppelin, it doesn't identify the notebook that it comes from.
We have thousands of notebooks.  The search doesn't work adequately to find the offending query and Zeppelin didn't show you the running notebooks in the UI.
So, how do you find these notebooks?
Searched on the UI for the query.

What RDBMS are you using? How are the users of Zeppelin signing into the database for querying? I'm assuming the overarching need is to know who to yell at (not so much which notebook), right?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
